# calling powershell functions through c#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to call PowerShell function through c# code.

```
**#This is sample PowerShell function**

function Add-num {

param($int1,$int2)

Write-Host ($int1 + $int2)

}


**#This is my c# code**

 class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String file = @"E:\powershell\Untitled3.ps1";

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();

            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript(file);
                PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Add-num").AddParameters(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"int1","6" },
                    {"int2","7" }
                });






               // Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

                foreach (PSObject outputItem in PowerShellInstance.Invoke())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject);
                }
                runspace.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll

Additional information: The term 'Add-num' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The above error is thrown when I execute this code. But when I run from PowerShell code works fine. I've checked the file path and file name everything is fine can anyone help me on this. The error is pointing at Invoke.

Comment: have you tried: [Executing PowerShell scripts from C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/) ?

Comment: I was able to execute any other scripts but not this script. For suppose I have $dateInput = 10
$dateInput

if($dateInput -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "null"
}
else {
    Write-Host "not null"
}     This script in another file and executed successfully.

Comment: *But when I run from PowerShell code works fine.* Are you saying that this command work fine in PowerShell: `.{E:\powershell\Untitled3.ps1} | Add-num -int1 '6' -int2 '7'`?

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following before:

```
string command = @"C:\temp.ps1";
var fileName = "powershell";
var args = $"-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted . '{command}'";

var process = CreateProcess(fileName, args);
process.Start();
```