# The term 'Add-Number' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: c#, powershell, c#-4.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

All I'm new to PowerShell and C# programming trying to complete some code.

Firstly I've written one function in PowerShell and code as below

```
function Add-Number{

param($int1,$int2)

Write-Host ($int1 + $int2)

}
```

Next, I'm writing the c# code and passing parameters to the PowerShell Add-Number function and code for c# as below.

```
namespace TestInputs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String file = @"E:\powershell\Untitled3.ps1";

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();

            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript(file);
                PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
                PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Add-Number");
                PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("int1", "10");
                PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("int2", "20");
                Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
                Console.WriteLine(PSOutput);
                Console.ReadKey();
                runspace.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the c# code

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll

Additional information: The term 'Add-Number' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Above Error was thrown.

My question can we able to pass parameters to script file using c# code if so how we can achieve this.???
Is there any way to assign values to PowerShell variables using c# code???

Comment: Are you the same person: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48418810?

Comment: The function hasn't been _created_ in your instance yet. The contents haven't been executed!

Answer (score 0):

Add-Number (as written) isn't a command let, it's just a function.  So to call it in a runspace you need to run script with the contents of "Add-Number -a 10 -b 20".

If you want to make your own command let, try a tutorial like this one:
[Using C# to Create PowerShell Cmdlets: The Basics](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-c-to-create-powershell-cmdlets-the-basics/)

Answer (score 0):

In the Untitled3.ps1 use the below code. Note I have not tested this but you get the idea.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int] $a,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int] $b
)

write-host ($a + $b)
```

And then in C# you can something like this.

```
        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            string script = $"{file} 10 20";
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript(script);
            PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
        }
```

Comment: PowerShell code is fine but the thing is I want to pass parameters through c# which is not working in your case as mine.